# Alternative form of $y = \frac{1}{1 - \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, derivatives, closed-form, trigonometric-integrals

I solved the differential equation $y'(x) = \frac{2}{a^2}xy^2(x)$ (with $y(0)=1$ and $x\in(-|a|,|a|)$) and came to
$$
y(x) = \frac{1}{1 - \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2}.
$$
This looks like some trigonometric *thing* to me. Do you know a better form for $y$?

Comment: You might think of $\tanh'(x)=\frac1{1-x^2}$

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Great, please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might think of $$
\tanh'(x)=\frac1{1-x^2}.
$$
So you get
$$
y(x)=\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x}a\right)^2}=\tanh'\left(\frac{x}a\right)
$$